# HCF of polynomials

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If hcf(P,Q)=hcf(P,R)=1 then hcf(P,QR)=1 ,how would I try a prove this, I tried using Bezout's Lemma to get APR-R=-B(QR), but how would I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility, using Bézout, is to find $s, t, u, v$ such that
$$
s P + t Q = 1 = u P + v R,
$$
and then compute
$$
1 = s P + t Q = s P + t Q \cdot 1 = s P +  t Q (u P + v R) = \dots
$$